# Nodes using Structs

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct{

      int key;
      int priority;
}array_node;


array_node *newNode(int key, int priority) {

     array_node *g;
     g = (array_node *)calloc(1,sizeof(array_node));

     if (NULL==g) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of mem!\n");
        return (NULL);
     }

     g->key=key;
     g->priority=priority;
     return g;
}

int main(){

    array_node *newNode;
    newNode->key = 5;
    newNode->priority = 1000;

    printf("%d\n",newNode->key);
}
```

Hi everyone! I need an insight on why I get segmentation fault whenever i compile the program. It seems like everything is fine but i don't know where the error is coming from.

I'm just implementing a node structs.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I guess `malloc(sizeof(array_node *))` should be changed into `malloc(sizeof(array_node))`.

Comment: It's like a reality show: "Type-a-question"

Comment: FYI I was still editing the post so there wasn't any questions yet.

Comment: @ms.sakura: next time please fully write the question before posting.

Comment: I kept on getting errors that's why. I will next time.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly:

```
g = (array_node *)malloc(sizeof(array_node *));
```

It should be

```
g = malloc(sizeof(array_node));
```

In first one you allocate memory for array_node pointer, but you need array_node object. When you later tried to do

```
g->key=key;
g->priority=priority;
```

You were referencing to somewhere in memory, but not to object component. Of course you unnecessary casted malloc return value to (array_node*), because in C you don't have to cast from void*. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) you can read about it.

Another error even more serious, because that is where your seg fault come from:

```
array_node *newNode;
newNode->key = 5;
newNode->priority = 1000;
```

Should be as another responder pointed out:

```
array_node* node = newNode(5, 1000);
```

In your version you just create a pointer to array_node object (just an address to memory), so you can't refer to key or priority because they don't exists.

---

Now i see that you changed malloc to

```
array_node *g;
g = (array_node *)calloc(1,sizeof(array_node));
```

Calloc you should use when you want to allocate memory for an array. In your case you should use malloc, which you can find above.

Comment: going to also comment that if this is C, you shouldn't be casting that malloc.

Comment: but if i don't cast it i get this error: my_heaps.c:78: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘array_node*’

Comment: That means you write in C++, not C. Unless you use C++ compiler. Either way correct your malloc and everything should work fine.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry, that inconsistency has been edited into this answer :), which was really just masking the problem that the malloc was creating a block of memory the size of an array_node pointer.

Comment: @ms.sakura, if you're coding in C++ you might as well use "new" rather than "calloc", otherwise you should be using malloc to allocate space for structs like these.

Comment: He write in C, but i think that he compile in C++ :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
// use these headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
  int key;
  int priority;
}array_node;

array_node *newNode(int key, int priority) {

  // sizeof(array_node), not sizeof(array_node) == sizeof(void*) == 4 or 8 typically
  array_node *g = malloc(sizeof(array_node));

  if (NULL==g) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Out of mem!\n");
     return (NULL);
  }

  g->key=key;
  g->priority=priority;
  return g;
}

int main(){
   /// call the function, not just type its name
   array_node* n = newNode(5, 1000);

   printf("Key = %d, Priority = %d\n", n->key, n->priority);

   return 0;
}
```

Watch for closing brackets, it is not Python, it is C. The printf() will not bother thinking for you. It will just print the address of n.

Comment: I followed everything you posted here but i get this error:
my_heaps.c: In function ‘array_node* newNode(int, int)’:
my_heaps.c:78: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘array_node*’

Comment: okay I was able to fix the problem by adding this
array_node *g = (array_node *)malloc(sizeof(array_node));

Thanks so mch

Comment: Then just leave the cast to (array_node*). The compiler you're using treats your file as C++ source, not plain C.

Answer (score 2):

Look in main():

```
array_node *newNode;
```

This pointer has an undefined value. The correct is:

```
array_node *node = newNode(5, 1000);
```

Comment: Probably because originally there was another mistake that was also causing problems; only making this change wouldn't have fixed the code.

Comment: Not entirely a good reason for downvoting this answer rather than upvoting the other answer though.

Comment: i get this error: my_heaps.c: In function ‘int main()’:
my_heaps.c:96: error: ‘newNode’ cannot be used as a function

Comment: +1 Because, based on the posted code, the `newNode()` function is irrelevant, since it is never called. The fact is a pointer is declared, but left uninitialized, and no memory is allocated, but then the (either garbage or NULL) pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: @ms.sakura Either you left `array_node *newNode;` unchanged, or you renamed the `newNode()` function.

Comment: @DennisMeng the other mistake was indeed a bug, but didn't cause any problems exactly because of what this answer describes. Whoever downvoted this did it without understanding what was going on.

Comment: I'm not saying I agree with whoever downvoted this; I was simply giving what I thought was a possible reason.